# Exporting audio from 3gp video files with AVAssetExportSession

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, 3gp, avassetexportsession

I am trying to export the audio from a 3gpp video file and it is not working... Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong? Here is the code I am using:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newFile.m4a"];
NSString *tempFile = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"oldFile.3gp"];

AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempFilePath] options:nil];
[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tracks"] completionHandler:^ {

    //HERE IS THE PROBLEM. THE ARRAY OF TRACKS IS EMPTY FOR SOME REASON.
    AVAssetTrack* audioTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];

    AVMutableComposition* audioComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack* audioCompositionTrack = [audioComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [audioCompositionTrack insertTimeRange:[audioTrack timeRange] ofTrack:audioTrack atTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1) error:nil];


    AVAssetExportSession *exprortSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:audioComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
    NSURL *toFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
    exprortSession.outputURL = toFileURL;
    exprortSession.outputFileType = @"com.apple.m4a-audio";

    NSLog(@"exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler will start");

    [exprortSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: ^(void) {

        if (exprortSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
            NSLog(@"Export success");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Export failed");
        }
    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to load the asset with

```
[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempFilePath] options:nil];
```

instead of

```
[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempFilePath] options:nil];
```

Comment: Yes. I can't believe I over looked that. Also in the output file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As your task will be manipulating the audio sample buffers directly you should use the second variant that AVFoundation will give you: paired AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter setup. You'll find proper sample code as in AVReaderWriterOSX from Apple developer source. This should also work with iOS besides you have different I/O format settings available. The availability to decompress audio as PCM and write back to uncompressed .wav or Audio  file should be given